# Capacitor/varistor replacement

Tags: capacitor

Can any one tell me what I would need to replace this yellow disc.  I have another board that this part has burned up, and I need to find a replacement.  The manufacturer is Buss, however I cannot find any information with the numbers printed on it.  The following is printed on the side:
Buss
M131
EL

I have also included a picture
Thanks in advance for your help
[image]

Comment: That looks like a varistor, not a capacitor. Why does it need replacement?

Comment: This is not the board that needs it, the one that needs it's burnt off the board, black and unreadable

Comment: Based on the number 130, it could be a varistor meant to tolerate 130 Vac for protecting 120 Vac mains voltage. But exact parameters are not known how much energy this can handle, as I could not find the datasheet easily.

Comment: Ok.  Well now I know a little more about it.  Thank you for your help

Comment: Buss stands for BUSSMANN. Bussmann and Cooper. It could be a MOV**14**131 where 14 stands for the disc diameter. I can find pictures, but no datasheet for those series. You need to find a datasheet to correctly determine what device you have.

Comment: The manufacturer is not Buss, but Bussman… You could please also provide the disc diameter?

Comment: What the fuse didn't blow?

Comment: If you are sure it's a varistor and you know the "working voltage" (the circuit voltage + some margin) you can take any varistor with compatible lead spacing. Take the one with the highest energy capacity.

Answer (score -1):

The correct size and speed of fuse must be used.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0CzIn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The withholding rating must be about 10% above max range voltage.

[here is a list of 14mm disks](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/filter/tvs-varistors-movs/141?s=N4IgjCBcpgbFoDGUBmBDANgZwKYBoQAHAFyhAGViAnASwDsBzEAgeygG0QBmLgTgCZYXEAF0AvgTC8AHLwQhkkdNnxFSkCtXpNWHEAAZREkPzABWCNAWpMuAiTIBVOjWIB5FAFkcaLAFcqHGYQNkhOMAB2MwA1YK5pGLizfViCQQAWVJMzLiz%2BZLyuTOCwaRSjAgBaM3lFZTs1MmDQzmFxKv5aqGo-VQcNZr0a9pBK%2BCtFHr71EEGwkHSjY075gDc0WixiFipRAhqrQigweyPIfLExIA)

Comment: What's the connection of your answer with the question? + The schematic doesn't make any sens. The symbol for the varistor is wrong.

Comment: @Fredled the choice of MOV/varistors was given. The symbol for varistors was not found. Capiche? The advice for fusing is essential for protection from MOV damage

Comment: -1 to Fred’s misunderstand

Comment: I agree about the fuse part but it's not answering the question and irrelevant because the OP is just replacing one part in an existing circuit.. You can edit a customized box when you don't find the symbol rather than using a misleading one. And what is a bidirectional TVS diode - also with a wrong symbol -  doing there?

Comment: Fred you miss a major point , not asked. how do you prevent the MOv from burning up in future. I think outside the box, you?

Comment: The fuse is an important part to improve the protection offered by the varistor. However, a varistor can already provide a good protection without a fuse. You can choose not to add a fuse for various reasons. Because varistors of this type can sustain at least 500A, and 2000A is common for still very affordable variants. More expensive ones, albeit not prohibitively, go up to 15000A. You need a big surge to blow a radial varistor.

Comment: The bidirectional (TVS) diode between the varistor and ground is bad because there should not be any impediment (impedance in the sens that it's an impediment to fuinctioning) between the varistor and ground. Nothing should be placed in the way of a varistor.

Comment: Fred led you failed to recognize that this MOV was blown up and there are proven ways to prevent that. this reminds me of a failure in design of a senior design colleague who put a gas tube and MOV in an offline power supply for a microwave repeater and it triggered then the follow on grid current created a crater hole in the PCB because he forgot to include current limiting. You are suggesting the same defective design strategy from this defective MOV, which was blown easily.  MOV’s also have limited surge uses before becoming useless when used within ratings of Joules, that’s an MTBF issue.

Comment: You failed to notice that the varistor was on an existing PCB, not of his fabrication. That he never said that there were no fuse on the PCB, and that in absent of fuse he can't add it to the PCB himself. I can still put an external one. I'm not suggesting a deffective design but design choice. For multiple reasons you can chose to add a varistor without a fuse and it will be already a million times better than no varistor and no fuse at all. One of the reason is that  there is almost always a current limiting device upstream.

Comment: To make a crater hole on a PCB protected by a MOV and a GDT, you need a solid current source. Either a circuit breaker would trip or a power supply would shut down before that happens,

Comment: I failed at no such thing. I merely suggested a design flaw that needed improvement. Your assumptions show lack of industry experience.  To make a crater in a 5W ISM band repeater in our case by a senior designer failed to recognize the follow on current damage much worse than the design in this question.

Comment: Today I discovered an excellent Chinese 100W 120Vac  Caterpillar brand fan that used an STM32 and 3 phase BLDC driver IC + FETs using a bridge diode ACDC filter. I am interfacing an Ethernet cable for remote vbl. speed control. but the AC wires had no solder on top pads or PTH and arced to my attention. Easily fixed but the design had PTC and MOV with S/W acceleration soft start. That’s I suggest.

Comment: That's fine. But you shouldn't feel offended if someone downvote your answer, I imagine it doesn't happen to you very often.... ;)

Comment: I am only offended by stupidity and my fat finger errors

Comment: @Andyaka needs to validate or be a  critical and not silent -1